# C# class design issue for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, class-design, mongodb-.net-driver

I got a problem in C# class design for mongodb, suppose there two class:

```
public class Group
{
    public Group()
    {
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

and there are two seperate collections corresponding to them in mongodb, the schema is like this:

```
Group:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e7839d90a2248d934c182bd"),
    "Name" : "Group1",
    "Users" : [ 
        {"_id": ObjectId("4e7839d90a2248d934c154af"), "Name": "User1"}
      ]
}
User:
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4e7839d90a2248d934c154af"),
    "Name" : "User1",
"Email": "some@some.com"
}
```

according to some Mongodb design principles, everytime when I want to display every users' name within a group, so I embed some user's fields in group collection,  thus only single one query is needed, but when inserting a Group object, all fields in each User object will be inserted, for example above: the email also will be inserted, which destroy the initial schema and occupy more space.  so how can I cut the User's email out when insert a Group object, do you guys have any good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because when denormalizing data you need to create separate class for each denormilized object. In your case for `User` within `Group` you need to create separate class like this one:

```
public class GroupUser
{
   public ObjectId Id {get;set;}

   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Then your `Group` class will looks like this:

```
public class Group
{
  public Group()
  {
    Users = new List<GroupUser>();
  }
  public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
  public List<GroupUser> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And when you inserting new `Group` you need to map data from regular user to denormalized `GroupUser`. So denormalization usual lead to a lot of mapping and extra classes. But it allow us to achieve high performance in data loading from a database.